# replaceChild jQuery equivalent

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to replace current dom element with new element i made.

I implemented following line

```
$(this).parent().replaceChild(newElem,this);
```

But it gives error saying `$(this).parent().replaceChild is not a function` because replaceChild is not a jQuery function, what would be equivalent in jQuery?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to use pure jQuery you can use the replaceWith method

```
$(this).replaceWith(newElem);
```

you can refer this link :

http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/

Answer (score 34):

If what you want is to replace the inside:

```
$(this).empty().append('<p>replacement</p>')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to replace the elements inside the parent, do the following.

**This is how to replace ALL children of an element:**

```
$(this).children().replaceWith(<div>hello world</div>)
```

**This is how to replace a specific child of an element by index:**

```
$($(this).children()[3]).replaceWith(<div>hello world</div>)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
$(this).parent().get().replaceChild(newElem,this);
```

If `$(this).parent()` is unique on the page. (`.get()` gives you the DOM object)

If you want to use pure `jQuery` you can use the `replaceWith` method

```
$(this).replaceWith(newElem);
```

Comment: it replaces parent element.

Comment: If you only want to replace the `current` element .. Remove `.parent`

Answer (score 0):

Try [replacewith()](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith)

```
$(this).parent().replaceWith(newElem);
```

Comment: it replaces parent element.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for a vanilla JS approach, use `replaceWith`:

```
this.replaceWith(newElem);
```